# Checking source file and automatically generating resx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, resources

Hello everyone here is my problem. I have the source file of a web page and it will be translated into different languages, so there are lots of `meta:resourcekey` keywords everywhere as you can imagine.

What I want is a plugin in VS that will first create a `resx` file and then check the whole code and whenever it sees the "`meta:resourcekey`" it will add a new string in the `resx` and copy whatever it sees on the right of "`meta:resourcekey`"

Can anyone help?

Comment: Seems more like .NET code then 'asp-classic'. Have you tagged this question correctly??

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, it seems I made a misclick there.